# Instance prototype objects behaving statically?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, prototype, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am attempting to make a game for Windows 8 using HTML/Javascript and WinJS, and am currently having problems with "prototypes" behaving statically when I don't want them to. I've never used Javascript to quite this extent, or with so many objects involved, so I have probably made a stupidly simple error, but I can't understand what.

First here is some of code (it is a long class) I'm talking about:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Race", {
        Car: WinJS.Class.derive(
            Race.Common,
            //Constructor method.
            function (slotNum, slotData, canvas, stage, preload, pixelScale) {
                this.canvas = canvas;
                this.stage = stage;
                this.preload = preload;
                this.pixelScale = pixelScale;

                this.slotNum = slotNum;
                this.slotData = slotData;
            },
            //Instance properties and methods.
            {
                /** Properties **/
                slotNum: 0,
                slotData: {},
                position: { x: 0, y: 0, r: 0 },
                lastPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, r: 0 },

                /**Methods **/
                /**
                 *
                 */
                calcRotation: function () {
                    //get angle between last position and current position

                    this.lastPosition.r = this.position.r;
                    this.position.r = this.getAngle(this.lastPosition.x, this.lastPosition.y, this.position.x, this.position.y);
                },
            },
            //Static properties and methods.
            {
                //Debug properties.
                showDebug: true,
                debugCarColors: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'],
            }
        )
    });
}());
```

So there are four instances of Race.Car, each with a different set of slotData. This works fine - each instance has its own set of slotData and its own slotNum. I can confirm this using breakpoints (as it cycles through the cars, the slotData is specific to each instance). As I've been dealing with just position so far, that has appeared to function correctly as well.

What I am having the issue with however is lastPosition. This is being set to the lastPosition for the *last* car, rather than the lastPosition for *this* car. I would have thought defining it in the "instance members" section of [WinJS.Class.define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/br229813.aspx) (rather than static members) and the use of this.lastPosition makes this obvious.

Why isn't it behaving as I expected and what am I doing wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you try to explicity declare the lastPosition to null? So in the constructor add a this.lastPosition = null.

Comment: Just throws an "unable to set property x of undefined" error. If I use "regular" properties (positionX, positionY, lastPositionX, lastPositionY) all works fine. I'm guessing defining position as an object literal, rather than doing something like new Coords(x, y, r) is the issue at the moment, but it seems long-winded to define a class just for a pair of coordinates.

Comment: Ah, so it should work when you add this.lastPosition = { x: 0, y: 0, r: 0 } to the constructor?

Comment: That works. :)  You should submit it as an answer. :P I think I understand why it didn't before either - the property was a single object instance and whatever changes made were happening to that single instance, rather than there being a different instance for each. By defining it in the constructor, there is an instance for each "Car".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When instantiating the object, try adding it as a default in the constructor, like this:

```
function (slotNum, slotData, canvas, stage, preload, pixelScale) {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.stage = stage;
            this.preload = preload;
            this.pixelScale = pixelScale;

            this.slotNum = slotNum;
            this.slotData = slotData;
            this.lastPosition = { x: 0, y: 0, r: 0 };
        },
```

Cheers :-)